# Why do viridis and hcl.color yield different colors?

Tags: r, viridis

I expected the calls below to `viridis` and `hcl.color` to output the same three colors:

```
> viridis::viridis(9) %>% sub("FF$", "", .)
[1] "#440154" "#472D7B" "#3B528B" "#2C728E" "#21908C" "#27AD81" "#5DC863" "#AADC32" "#FDE725"
> viridisLite::viridis(9) %>% sub("FF$", "", .)
[1] "#440154" "#472D7B" "#3B528B" "#2C728E" "#21908C" "#27AD81" "#5DC863" "#AADC32" "#FDE725"
> grDevices::hcl.colors(9, palette = "viridis")
[1] "#4B0055" "#403173" "#00588B" "#007B97" "#009B95" "#00B785" "#53CC67" "#B2DC3C" "#FDE333"
> colorspace::sequential_hcl(9, "Viridis")
[1] "#4B0055" "#403173" "#00588B" "#007B97" "#009B95" "#00B785" "#53CC67" "#B2DC3C" "#FDE333"
```

However, these functions generate slightly different colors:
[image]

Is this expected? What am I missing about the differences between these functions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The differences in colors between `viridis` and `hcl.colors` with `palette = "viridis"` are expected because they operate in different color spaces, and the mapping between these spaces may not perfectly preserve the original colors. If you want to use the `"viridis"` palette, it's recommended to directly use the `viridis` function to ensure consistent and perceptually uniform colors.

Edit:

`viridis` typically generates colors in the `HSL` (Hue, Saturation, Lightness) color space.

`hcl.color` generates colors in the `HCL` (Hue, Chroma, Luminance) color space.

Comment: That makes sense for the interpolated values and the colorspace of that interpolation (LAB, RGB, HCV, HCL). But I don't think that explains why the values at the extremes of the range are not the same.